# Crystal Reports I get "Load Report Failed' error?

Tags: sql, vb.net, crystal-reports

Here's my code for crystal reports:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim SqlConn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=classified; Database= classified; User Id= classified; password= classified")
    Dim value As String = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath
    Dim path As String = "H:\Auto Dealer Project\Public"

    ' Determine whether the directory exists. 

    If Directory.Exists(path) Then
        Console.WriteLine("That specified path exists already.")
    End If
    Dim dirpath As DirectoryInfo = Directory.CreateDirectory(path)
    Console.WriteLine("Temp directory was created:", Directory.GetCreationTime(path))
    ' To load the crystal report in to the report document

    cryRpt.Load(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\CrystalExport.pdf")

    MessageBox.Show(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, path)

    ' to update the cystal report

    cryRpt.Refresh()
    Try
        Dim CrExportOptions As ExportOptions
        Dim CrDiskFileDestinationOptions As New DiskFileDestinationOptions()
        Dim CrFormatTypeOptions As New PdfRtfWordFormatOptions()
        CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = "H:\Auto Dealer Project\Public\CrystalExport.pdf"
        CrExportOptions = cryRpt.ExportOptions
        With CrExportOptions
            .ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile
            .ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat
            .DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions
            .FormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions
        End With
        cryRpt.Export()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try

End Sub
```

I get the error "Load Report Failed" on the line

```
    cryRpt.Load(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\CrystalExport.pdf")
```

To me it's probably just me doing something stupid, but what do you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

you set path up at the top of your code like this

`Dim path As String = "H:\Auto Dealer Project\Public"`

but then look for your report a different way.

Are you certain the path My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\CrystalExport.pdf" actually leads where you think it does?

Put a break point on that line and make sure the path leads to the right place. Generally you get the load report error if the report doesn't exist (because it's not in the folder you thought it was)

Comment: This is not answer, just advance. So make this comment

Comment: If his expected file path and actual path are not the same, then this is the answer. Couldn't leave it as a comment even if I wanted to, commenting is reserved for users with 50 rep or more.